# How to use a single webView for multiple buttons in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing my android application (Java) in android studio i am new to this.

there are two fragments A & B,
**fragment A** contains multiple buttons *(different buttons with different links)* and
**fragment b** contain webview.
I tried but the application is crashing  when click the button.

**Fragment A code**

```
      String[] urls=new String[6];
      Bundle bundle;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_external_links, container, false);




        LinearLayout fb_link = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fb_link_icon);
        fb_link.setOnClickListener(this);
        urls[0] ="https://facebook.com";



        LinearLayout google_link = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.google_link_icon);
        google_link.setOnClickListener(this);
        urls[1] ="https://google.com";


        LinearLayout hotmail_link = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.hotmail_link_icon);
        hotmail_link.setOnClickListener(this);
        urls[2] ="https://hotmail.com";


        LinearLayout yahoo_link = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.yahoo_link_icon);
        yahoo_link.setOnClickListener(this);
   //     urls[3] ="https://yahoo.com";




        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.fb_link_icon:
                fragment = new WebViewFragment();

                  bundle.putString("links" , urls[0]);
                  fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                  replaceFragment(fragment);

                break;


            case R.id.google_link_icon:
                fragment = new WebViewFragment();

                  bundle.putString("links" , urls[1]);
                  fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                  replaceFragment(fragment);

                break;



            case R.id.hotmail_link_icon:
                fragment = new WebViewFragment();

                  bundle.putString("links" , urls[2]);
                  fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                  replaceFragment(fragment);

                break;
        }

    }



    public void replaceFragment(Fragment Fragment){
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, Fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();


    }

    }
```

**fragment B code**

```
WebView webview;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_view, container, false);


        webview.findViewById(R.id.webview_frame);


          Bundle bundle =  this.getArguments();
          String website = bundle.getString("links");
          String webSite = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("links");



        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
          webview.loadUrl(website);

        WebSettings websettings = webview.getSettings();
        websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: What error you getting in logcat ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to:
clarify title of question, more details or clarify of problem, include error message, include the expected result.
See [ask]